# Greek localization not shown in appstore

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I had uploaded an app and recently I tried to localize it.
The default language is English but I want it also in Greek(the app is a Greek one).
I have created the metadata in iTunes connect and also I have added Greek as the active language.
I have also successfully localized the project. Even the bundle display name works.
The problem is that in the app-store the English name and description are shown, even in the Greek app-store.
Also in the version summary in iTunes connect, when Greece is selected it shows the English description.

Is there a selection available to tell the Greek app-store that it needs the Greek translated metadata? Do I have to add any row in app's plist?
I saw that there are some keys that are for localization but I haven't tried them yet.
Also I have localized only the bundle display name. Do I need to localize also the bundle name? I don't think that app-store takes these data from the plist.

Comment: Explain the problem and then try to put your question in one line to make our life easier.

Comment: could not this depend on your browser/OS system language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Greek App Store is not localized.
So everything will appear in English.

In order your app to show the Greek translation, you'll have to switch your phone's language to Greek and test the app this way.

If it's not appearing in Greek then, you should verify that the localizable.strings file is correctly set up in your project.

Also you should do, what most Greek developers are doing, meaning enter the Greek description in the English metadata section.

Comment: And how I can have different names for world and different for greek appstore? Different apps?

Comment: I have done this and it works. I want different name in appstore.

Comment: You can add more supported app stores and define the app name for each store. There is no need to create multiple versions of your app

Comment: How can I do this? I have already set it up in ITC I think.How I add supported appstores?

Comment: Just edit your application and add another localization in ITC. Then you can change the App name in each supported localization. For the Greek Store, as it's not localized, like I said, you cannot add a different name or description